'Undefined control sequence' error
I have a Git repository with TeX sources which I generate a PDF file from. Last time I committed some changes and successfully generated a PDF from it was April 22 this year.
However when I opened the project in Kile today and tried to create a PDF file I got a lot of errors Undefined control sequence.
What could have changed since then? I remember that I updated Ubuntu from 22 to 24 in the meantime. However it's hard for me to figure out what exactly has caused this as I don't use TeX very often. Are TeX related packages missing/outdated? Has TeX syntax changed?
Here is the minimal code samle to reproduce the problem:
    \documentclass[a4paper,openbib,11pt]{article}
    
    \usepackage[default]{opensans}
    
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fltpoint}
    
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \definecolor{refcolor}{rgb}{0,0,1}
    \usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=refcolor, filecolor=refcolor, citecolor=refcolor, urlcolor=refcolor]{hyperref}
    
    \usepackage[top=1.4cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
    \setlength{\footskip}{0.7cm}
    \usepackage[russian=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
    \begin{document}
    \newcommand{\link}[2]{\htmladdnormallink{#1}{#2}}
    \sloppy
    \link{Stackoverflow}{http://stackoverflow.com/users/971355/user} 
    \end{document}

The error in Kile:
[PDFLaTeX] test.tex => test.pdf (pdflatex)
[PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1
./test.tex:24:Undefined control sequence \link
[PDFLaTeX] 1 error, 0 warnings, 0 badboxes

Versions of related tools/packages that I can think of:
$ pdflatex -v
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian)

texlive:
$ apt show texlive*|grep -E "(Package:|Version:)"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Package: texlive-binaries
Version: 2023.20230311.66589-9build3
Package: texlive-lang-french
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-latex-base
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-latex-recommended
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-fonts-recommended
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-latex-extra
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-plain-generic
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-portuguese
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-base
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-arabic
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-bibtex-extra
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-publishers
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-science
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-pstricks
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-fonts-extra
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-xetex
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-formats-extra
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-metapost
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-extra-utils
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-all
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-cyrillic
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-pictures
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-font-utils
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-games
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-luatex
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-korean
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-other
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-chinese
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-cjk
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-japanese
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-european
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-fonts-extra-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-fonts-extra-links
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-full
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-humanities
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-humanities-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-czechslovak
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-english
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-german
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-greek
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-italian
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-polish
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-lang-spanish
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-latex-base-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-latex-extra-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-latex-recommended-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-metapost-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-music
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-pictures-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-pstricks-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-publishers-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-science-doc
Version: 2023.20240207-1
Package: texlive-binaries-sse2
Version: 2023.20230311.66589-9build3
Package: texlive-base-bin
Package: texlive-context
Package: texlive-latex3
Package: texlive-math-extra
Package: texlive-common
Package: texlive-lang-arab
Package: texlive-htmlxml


Use \href{http://stackoverflow.com/users/971355/user}{Stackoverflow}

\link is not a command I recognise and certainly is not defined by any of the packages you show in the example. So that example would have always given that error, it is not due to any update.

@DavidCarlisle Yes, thanks. I've added it. Right after \begin{document}.
The error hasn't changed.

obviously the error message does change if you define \link.  You no longer get an error that \link is undefined, you get an error that \htmladdnormallink is undefined. Where have you seen \htmladdnormallink documented? It is not a command a recognise. Use the form in Samcarter's comment above

\htmladdnormallink has been removed some years ago. Use \href.

@DavidCarlisle the (imho undocumented) htmladdnormallink was in hyperref some years ago, (to support the html package if i remember correctly) , but it has been removed.

@UlrikeFischer you can answer, I can't risk getting 15 just at the moment:-)

\htmladdnormallink is not a documented hyperref command. It was provided by hyperref for some time to keep hyperref compatible with latex2html but now latex2html does that directly and so the compability layer has been removed from hyperref. Use the \href command instead. Be aware that you need to change the order of the arguments:
\newcommand{\link}[2]{\href{#2}{#1}} 


Strange that it still worked this spring. I regularly update Ubuntu and all the installed packages via apt

the command was removed begin of 2022, so with an updated texlive 2022 it is undefined.
